# created the nexus 5 emulator in android studio its show only black screen?

Tags: android-studio

I created the nexus 5 and nexus 7 emulator in android studio. I launch the both emulator one by one. Nexus 7 emulator is working fine but in nexus 5 contains only the black screen i waited more than 1 hour. what was the problem.

It shows the message in:

```
        emulator: device fd:628
        HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
        emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
        emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
        emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
        emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
```

The details of nexus 5 emulator

Name: Nexus_5_API_21 CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86) Path: C:\xxx.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21.avd 
Target: Android 5.0.1 (API level 21)
Skin: nexus_5 
SD Card: \Nexus_5_API_21.avd\sdcard.img 
Snapshot: yes hw.dPad: no runtime.network.speed: full hw.accelerometer: yes hw.device.name: Nexus 5 vm.heapSize: 64 skin.dynamic: yes hw.device.manufacturer: Google hw.gps: yes hw.audioInput: yes tag.id: default hw.camera.back: none hw.mainKeys: no AvdId: Nexus_5_API_21 hw.camera.front: none hw.lcd.density: 480 runtime.scalefactor: auto avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 21 snapshot.present: yes hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88 hw.ramSize: 1536 hw.trackBall: no hw.battery: yes hw.sdCard: yes tag.display: Default runtime.network.latency: none hw.keyboard: yes hw.sensors.proximity: yes disk.dataPartition.size: 200M hw.sensors.orientation: yes avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8 hw.gpu.enabled: no

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the maximum RAM size supported by the HAXM is 512 MB.Try bringing down the size of the emulator RAM to 512 MB.This solved the issue for me.